# Как можно выполнить подцикл FOR в (отдельных) нескольких потоках параллельно в C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть такой код с двумя циклами for:

```
for (int a = 0; a < numb1; a++)
 {
//тут весь код для запуска и работы потоков для цикла ниже.
for (int d = 0; d < numb2; d++)//нужно чтобы этот подцикл выполнялся в 10 потоках (не суть количество потоков может быть разное) паралельно.
 {
 //тут не важно (код для выполнения в потоках).
 }
}
```

нужно чтобы второй внутренний цикл выполнялся в отдельных параллельных потоках,  и желательно весь код для запуска потоков  поместился бы внутрь первого цикла ,такое как то можно реализовать вообще на C#?

Comment: а чем вам Thread не угодил?

Comment: дело в том что этот весь код и так выполняется в многопотоке а мне нужно чтобы  цикл FOR второй выполнялся в отдельных в параллельных потоках...

Comment: Можно. То что вы хотите называется распаралеливание. Почитайте "c# как распараллелить цикл", или как распаралелить конкретную задачу. Вот например http://regfordev.blogspot.com/2011/04/blog-post.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

всё просто

```
for (int a = 0; a < numb1; a++)
{
    Parallel.For(0, numb2, d => {
        //тут не важно (код для выполнения в потоках).
    });
}
```

С указанием количества потоков

```
for (int a = 0; a < numb1; a++)
{
    Parallel.For(
        0, 
        numb2, 
        new ParallelOptions() {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 42}, 
        d =>
        {
            //тут не важно (код для выполнения в потоках).
        });
}
```

Comment: Parallel.For не пойдет к сожаленью, нужно чтобы количество потоков можно было указывать именно...

Comment: @GeneratorSveta обновил ответ

Comment: ок спс щас попробую, почему попробую потому что вроде как Parallel.For он потоки сам ставит в зависимости от ядер процессора как помню, хотя может путаю...

Comment: @GeneratorSveta сам ставит, если вы не укажете ему явно сколько потоков вам надо

Answer (score 3):

Тут есть несколько вариантов решения (как всегда в программировании :D)
Вы можете, как уже говорилось ранее, распараллелить этот цикл руками, используя `Thread`/`ThreadPool`/`Tasks` и т.д.
Но скорее всего вы хотите использовать что-то вроде класа [Parallel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), в котором уже есть метод For, распараллеливающий это за вас :D
Его вызов будет выглядеть у вас как-то так:

```
Parallel.For(0, numb2, (x)=>{ /* а тут 'неважный' код */})
```

Comment: Parallel.For не пойдет к сожаленью, нужно чтобы количество потоков можно было указывать именно...

Comment: @GeneratorSveta, скорее всего не верна сама идея того, что планируется сделать, но это не мне судить) Самая не затратная по коду реализация это через ThreadPool :D

Comment: думал чисто цикл можно так запустить без использования тредпула , по ThreadPool можно вариант именно на основе этого же кода, как именно вы предлагаете это реализовать с ThreadPool?

Comment: @generatorSveta, просто выставить в пуле потоков ограничение на количество потоков (`threadPool.SetMaxThreads`), которые вам необходимо. Для кода внутри чикла лучше создать метод (а не использовать лямбда выражение, т.к. в этом случае они могут испортить данные из-за захвата) и просто оставить этот цикл, а в нём вызывать `QueueUserWorkItem` с нашим методом.

Comment: ок спс щас попробую с пулом а по ответу выше с ламбда выражением как там использовать можно операторы continue и break? ато вызывают ошибку: "Невозможно передать управление из тела анонимного метода или лямбда-выражения" эти два оператора в коде...

Comment: @GeneratorSveta, использование `continue` и `break` просто не имеют смысла. Зачем нам использовать `continue` если они итак выполняются параллельно. А вместо `break` нам просто нужно сделать `return`.

Comment: по break ясно а вот по continue там просто он выполняется по некторым условиям if и их там две и условия эти важные...

Comment: @GeneratorSveta, тебе не нужен continue потому что у тебя они все итак выполняются одновременно (на самом деле нет, но для абстракции и понимая так проще) и тебе не нужно переключаться на выполнения следующего, просто поменяй continue на return. Ну и вот нашёлся вариант с `Parallel.For` в другом ответе :3