# Как многопоточно обрабатывать данные из списка?

Tags: c#, async-await

Как на C# многопоточно обрабатывать данные из списка(очереди)?
Есть список url, с которых надо загрузить данные и их обработать.
Как правильно организовать код,что б создалось например только 10 потоков и каждый поток брал ссылку из списка,удалял её в списке или очереди,загружал данные и как выполнит действия-забирал следующий элемент списка.
Ну и так,что б элемент списка блокировался на время доступа другого потока.

Как организовать это?
Читаю семафоры,мьютексы,но пока не вник в это.

---

подкорректировал :
Я хотел многопоточность изначально, но лучше совместить с асинхронностью. То-есть нет смысла ждать ответ от удалённого сервера. Если в главном потоке делать, то он подвиснет. По-этому сдлав асинхронно- сам поток не будет ждать, когда будет ответ от сервера. Но на одном потоке выигрыша не будет. Если сразу запускаем например 10 потоков, то мы посылаем 10 запросов и ждём(внутри потока асинхронность используем и даже каждый десятый поток не напрягаем в момент ожидания,но асинхронность я могу сделать,а вот многопоточность в очереди пока что не могу),потом каждый поток,получив данные,выполняет действия и затем переходит к следующей порции. То-есть потоки не создаются миллион раз. Они создались сразу и выполняют задачи из очереди.

Создать 10 потоков и сказать каждому -> async **GetMyData_and_Save_Data()**

,где метод **GetMyData_and_Save_Data()** берёт ссылку из очереди , качает асинхронно(ну скачивание то я сделаю,это не сложно), ну и потом обрабатывает асинхронно, а потом повторяет, то-еть находится в цикле while, а как очередь будет пуста, то вылетает с метода и поток уничтожается.

Спасибо

Comment: Кажеться семафоры и мьютексы это не для C#. Поделить список на 10 (обстрактно), и запустите 10 потоков с частями списка. На самом деле, потоков разумно делать не более чем колличество процессоров, или кратное этому числу. Таски тут лучше не применять, не даст выигрыша во времени и производительности.

Comment: Смущают метки: зачем `pthread` и `android-asynctask`? К тому же `async-await` означает асинхронность, а это не совсем то же, что многопоточность. В общем, приведите более точный пример того, что нужно сделать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov исправил. На телефоне нечайно близлежащие выбрал. И так 2 раза

Comment: @NewView  ну как я понял,выигрыш в данном случае будет,если потоков более,чем ядер/процессоров. Так как узпое место,это ожидание удалённого сервера

Comment: Запуск каждого потока это тяжёлая и время емкая операция, если обрабатываемые данные малы, то выигрыша по времени и производительности можно не получить вообще. А даже наоборот, замедлить выполнение.

Comment: Сервера в списке разные? Если есть одинаковые, то используйте "keep-alive" без сброса соединения, не нужно будет лишний раз переподключаться к серверу.

Comment: Пишу с телефона, потому не ручаюсь за правильность, но `var parsed = urlList.Parallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(10).Select(url=>parser.Parse(url)).ToList();` распарсит вам ваши урлы параллельно в 10 потоков и сложит результат в список.

Comment: Также поглядите [пример асинхронного парсинга](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/752573/Увеличить-скорость-парсера/752593#752593)

Comment: [Параллельные циклы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/857562/Как-можно-выполнить-подцикл-for-в-отдельных-нескольких-потоках-параллельно-в-c/857593#857593)

Comment: [Ограничиваем количество потоков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846530/semaphore-в-tpl/846539#846539) - хотя откуда у вас число 10? И почему бы пулу потоков самому не решить сколько выделить потоков?

Comment: И, я бы на вашем месте изучил разницу между многопоточностью и асинхронностью. Важно понимать, что чтобы качать параллельно и асинхронно 10 урлов не обязательно занимать 10 потоков

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну это очень спорный момент, почему вы решили, что это дубликат именно prod/cons? Тут задачу можно решить разными способами, оч спорно в общем

Comment: @tym32167, как хотите, переоткрыл

Comment: Роман, судя по активности в вашей теме: есть много комментариев и есть ответы - народ рвется в бой и хочет вам помочь. Но все мы ждем _уточнения_ вашего сценария. Повторю: _асинхронность != многопоточность_. Если проблема в _скачивании_, то это IO-операции и тут нужна асинхронность. Если проблема в _обработке_ данных, то это CPU-нагрузка и тут нужна многопоточность. Так что опишите _точно_, что вам нужно. Возможно, нужно совместить и то, и другое.

Comment: @"Alexander Petrov" спасибо. Я хотел многопоточность изначально, но лучше совместить с асинхронностью. То-есть нет смысла ждать ответ от удалённого сервера. Если в главном потоке делать, то он подвиснет. По-этому сдлав асинхронно- сам поток не будет ждать, когда будет ответ от сервера. Но на одном потоке выигрыша не будет. Если сразу запускаем например 10 потоков, то мы посылаем 10 запросов и ждём(внутри потока асинхронность используем и даже каждый десятый поток не напрягаем в момент ожидания),потом каждый поток,получив данные,выполняет действия и затем переходит к следующей порции.

Comment: 1) сколько хостов надо опросить?  2) какой объем данных?

Answer (score 4):

Предлагаю данное решение, довольно таки простое, вместо `List` для `_linkQueue` можно использовать потокобезопасный `ConcurrentQueue`.

```
    private List<string> _linkQueue = new List<string>();
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(10);

    public async Task ProcessData()
    {
        var taskPool = new List<Task>(10);

        foreach (var link in _linkQueue)
        {
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            taskPool.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                ProcessItem(link);
                _semaphore.Release();
            }));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(taskPool.ToArray()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

UPD

А можно вообще с данным примером не использовать потокобезопасные коллекции.

Comment: Интересно и почему минус? Решение вроде бы правильное , ну ладно

Answer (score 3):

На тему многопоточности и асинхронности есть много вопросов на ru.so, с очень хорошими и подробными ответами, но всё же, судя по ответам и комментариям в этой теме, нужно ещё раз всё объяснить.

Допустим имеется следующий код, выполняющий получение данных последовательно:

```
var urls = new List<string>
{
    @"http:\\ru.stackoverflow.com", @"http:\\yandex.ru", @"http:\\google.ru"
};

foreach (var url in urls)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    var text = client.DownloadString(url);
    rtb.AppendText(url + " : " + text.Length + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Как мы видим, есть список урлов из которых мы в цикле последовательно получаем текст и выводим в `RichTextBox`.

Если поместить этот код в баттон-клик формы WinForms и выполнить, можно легко заметить, что форма на время его выполнения замерзает.

---

Попробуем сделать многопоточность с использованием Parallel LINQ (в комментариях приведён один из вариантов):

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    urls.AsParallel()
        .WithDegreeOfParallelism(10)
        .ForAll(url =>
        {
            var client = new WebClient();
            var text = client.DownloadString(url);
            rtb.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                rtb.AppendText(url + " : " + text.Length + Environment.NewLine)));
        });
});
```

`Task.Run` здесь нужен по двум причинам: во-первых, чтобы не замерзала форма, во-вторых, чтобы не попасть в дедлок (нужно обращение к текстбоксу).

С одной стороны, это очень простой код. Всё распараллеливание берёт на себя система. С другой стороны, долгая операция в нашем код - именно запрос к серверам. Это IO-bound код. Сам по себе он выполняется асинхронно на IOCP. А мы насоздавали потоков, которые по сути не нужны. (Вообще, операционная система довольно умная и заметит долгое ожидание IO-операций и грамотно использует потоки, отдав их другим процессам, но не будем углубляться...)

Этот код станет иметь больше смысла, если, например, после получения данных они будут долго обрабатываться (CPU-bound - нагрузка на процессор):

```
var text = client.DownloadString(url);
VeryLongProcessData(text);
```

Тут потоки будут использоваться более эффективно, но первая часть кода пока далека от совершенства.

---

Сделаем получение данных асинхронно, но последовательно (метод пометить `async`).

```
foreach (var url in urls)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    var text = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
    rtb.AppendText(url + " : " + text.Length + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Тут пока ещё идёт последовательная работа с серверами, но форма уже не замерзает.

Сделаем запросы асинхронно и одновременно:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

foreach (var url in urls)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    var task = client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
    tasks.Add(task);
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    rtb.AppendText(task.Result.Length + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

В данном коде задачи создаются и помещаются в список. Обратите внимание, что в цикле нет `await`! Благодаря этому все запросы уходят на выполнение параллельно. А ожидание их завершения выполняется в методе `WhenAll`.

В этом примере не создаётся ни одного потока! Круто, правда?

Правда, тут недостаток в том, что сперва ожидается завершение *всех* задач и лишь затем можно обработать полученные данные. Если погуглить, можно найти использование метода `Task.WhenAny`, но не буду слишком удлинять текст.

---

Давайте теперь совместим асинхронное выполнение запросов и многопоточную обработку данных.

В данном конкретном случае очень удобно применить *продолжение*:

```
//var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var url in urls)
{
    var client = new WebClient();

    var task = client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url)
        .ContinueWith(
            t => rtb.AppendText(url + " : " + t.Result.Length + Environment.NewLine),
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskContinuationOptions.LongRunning,
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    //tasks.Add(task);
}

//await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Что мы имеем: сперва на каждый урл выполняется асинхронный запрос (без создания потока), а затем, после завершения запроса выполняется обработка данных в потоке.

Это весьма эффективно (и просто). Единственно, тут не сделано ограничение максимального количества задач/потоков.

В методе `ContinueWith` можно выполнить любые действия после завершения получения данных. Если это действительно долгие вычисления, добавляем опцию `LongRunning`. Так как у нас есть обращение к гуевому контролу, передаём шедулер с контекстом синхронизации (соответственно, если работы с гуем нет, он не нужен).

В данном случае каждая задача выполняется независимо от других. Если нужно выполнить какие-либо действия после завершения всех задач, то нужно раскомментировать код.

---

Я в очередной раз убедился, что объясняльщик из меня плохой. Но всё же надеюсь, что смог донести разницу между асинхронным и многопоточным кодом.

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, каким именно образом можно одновременно и удалить элемент из очереди, и заблокировать его от других потоков. Предлагаю такое решение

```
class Program
{
    private static ConcurrentQueue<string> _urlQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parallel.For(0,
            _urlQueue.Count,
            new ParallelOptions() {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10},
            _ =>
            {
                _urlQueue.TryDequeue(out var link);
                // your code
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: При минусовании просьба хотя бы сообщать, что не так.

Answer (score -1):

Используйте потокобезопасный список Queue.

```
        public const int _taskPoolSize = 10;
        private void MainThread() {
            var myData = GetData();
            var taskFact = new TaskFactory();
            var taskPool = new Task[_taskPoolSize];
            for(var i = 0; i < _taskPoolSize; i++) {
                taskPool[i] = taskFact.StartNew(() => {
                    while (myData.Count > 0) {
                        var data = myData.Dequeue();
                        //other code
                    }
                });
            }
            Task.WaitAll(taskPool);
        }

        public Queue<string> GetData() {
            return new Queue<string>();
        }
```

Comment: Из какого пространства имён этот `Queue`? Что-то не похож он на потокобезопасный...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov мне кажется он хотел использоваться ConcurrentQueue